# Proper Custom View Construction In Android

Tags: android

I'd like to know if its considered bad practice to inflate child view from within a custom view's constructor, and if so maybe a reason as to why this is so ?

```
public class MyLinearLayout : LinearLayout
{ 
    public MyLinearLayout (Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes) 
    { 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

        View child = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ChildView, null);

        this.AddView(child);
    }
}
```

versus

```
public class MyLinearLayout : LinearLayout
{ 
    public MyLinearLayout (Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes) 
    { 
        View child = new ChildView(context);
        child.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParameters(...);

        this.AddView(child);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with this approach, as it can be found in classes like `NumberPicker`. If you use the `LayoutInflater.inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)` method to attach to the root view, you can use `Merge` optimizations. E.g.

`View child = inflater.Inflate(R.layout.ChildView, this, true);`

Comment: That form of the call will take advantage of merge AND include tags ?!

Comment: Not sure on the includes, but I don't see why not. Please update here if you find out.